# Trying to add an image to a tkinter app but it won't load the image

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to add an image to an application without using `PIL` because I don't have access to it on my school pc. So I'm trying to use `PhotoImage` but when I run the program it just gives me a white screen with nothing on it. I've been trying to do this for the last 4 hrs and advice would be helpful.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage

master = Tk()

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
var11 = IntVar()
var12 = IntVar()
var13 = IntVar()
var14 = IntVar()
var15 = IntVar()
var16 = IntVar()
var17 = IntVar()
var18 = IntVar()


def var_state1():
    if var1.get() == TRUE and var2.get() == TRUE and var3.get() == TRUE:
        print("it workd1")

def Before_Day():

    # this is the image
    image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logo.png')
    Label(master, image=image).grid(row=0, sticky=W)

    Label(master, text="Check When Complete:").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Icecream Mashine", variable=var1).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Radio", variable=var2).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Oven", variable=var3).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
    crl1 = Button(master, text="Done", command=var_state1).grid(row=5, sticky=W, pady=4)


Before_Day()
mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the problem may be because `image` is a variable  local to your `Before_Day()` function and is discarded when it returns. To avoid that, make it an attribute of the `Tk` instance with `master.image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logo.png')` and change the line `Label(master, image=master.image).grid(row=0, sticky=W)` to reference it.

Comment: how would I reference that, I'm new to the language sorry for the stupid questions?

Comment: After making it an attribute, use `master.image` instead of plain `image` whenever you need to reference it — as shown in the change to line that creates the `Label` (which I also suggested changing). Since `master` is a global variable, its attributes are also effectively global.

Comment: ooohok i got it thanks for the help any way i can resize the image?

Comment: I think you'll need to use the PIL/Pillow module  to do image resizing. You can get it from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). PIL images have a [`resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay except for a few things. The 'image' you are creating gets lost when the program reaches mainloop(), which is because you created it inside the Before_Day() function.

One easy change you can make is move this line at the top (i.e. outside the Before_Day() function) and then use it directly as global variable.

```
image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logo.png')
```

Just write this code after the 'var18 = IntVar()' line. And also remember not to use pack() with label when you use grid().

To be more precise, you can see the exact code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import PhotoImage

master = Tk()

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
var11 = IntVar()
var12 = IntVar()
var13 = IntVar()
var14 = IntVar()
var15 = IntVar()
var16 = IntVar()
var17 = IntVar()
var18 = IntVar()
image = PhotoImage(file='C:/Users/plarkin2020334/Pictures/DQ_Logo.png')

def var_state1():
    if var1.get() == TRUE and var2.get() == TRUE and var3.get() == TRUE:
        print("it workd1")

def Before_Day():
    # this is the image
    Label(master, image=image).grid(row=0, sticky=W)

    Label(master, text="Check When Complete:").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Icecream Mashine", variable=var1).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Radio", variable=var2).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    Checkbutton(master, text="Turn On Oven", variable=var3).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
    crl1 = Button(master, text="Done", command=var_state1).grid(row=5, sticky=W, pady=4)


Before_Day()
mainloop()
```

This should work fine! I hope this helped.
Best of luck! :-)